# map with named function vs identical lambda function providing different responses, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a simple function to extract the month from a string column in a pandas dataframe, where the string is of the form m/d/yyyy.

The dataframe is called data, the date column is called transaction date, and my new proposed month column I wish to call transaction month.

The below works just fine:

```
data['transaction month']=data['transaction date'].map(lambda x: x[0:x.index('/')])
```

However, if I try to do the same thing with a named function, it just returns a column where every value is `None`

```
def extract_month_from_date(date):
        return date[0:date.index('/')]

data['transaction month 2']=data['transaction date'].map(extract_month_from_date)
```

I've stared at the code for long enough that I think I'm going crazy, what's wrong with the

Comment: Please provide an example input that can be copied and pasted into our editors. ... Please read [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure you remembered to `return` in your real code?

Comment: the two functions are equivalent and will produce the same output, you likely have a typo in the actual code you ran

Comment: I would avoid splitting strings by characters. It's inefficient, especially since there are tools to convert strings to `datetime` and extract month directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the month via [`pd.Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['8/2/2018']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month

#         date  month
# 0 2018-08-02      8
```